React-moralis doesnt seem to work with NextJs14 , any alternatives?
The react-moralis package doesnt seem to be working with Nextjs14, there are several issues raised in the react-moralis github repo about this , but i think the package is not managed by the community anymore , is there any other similar alternatives which can work with Nextjs14 for connecting web3 to the frontend ?

These are some of the alternatives:

wagmi
web3-react
usedapp

I would personally recommend wagmi, mainly because of the availability of extensive documentation and examples.
You can read about the comparison.
And, create-wagmi (i.e., a CLI for scaffolding new Wagmi projects) comes with a wide variety of templates including:

next: A Next.js Wagmi project.
nuxt: A Nuxt Wagmi project.
vite-react (default): A Vite (React) Wagmi project.
vite-vanilla: A Vite Wagmi Core project.
vite-vue: A Vite (Vue) Wagmi project.


Thanks a Lot Syed , i was having a hard time finding out alternative , you made it a lot easier for me , i think i would go with wagmi too because of its extensive documentation as you said.

You’re welcome, @HarigovindMG. Happy coding!
